# flutter 1.9 yaml file for mobile and web app?

Tags: flutter, yaml

My flutter app runs fine on android and now I'm trying to build it as a web app. I followed the directions [on flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web), but am getting the following errors:

```
Skipping compiling myapp|lib/main_web_entrypoint.dart with ddc because some of its
transitive libraries have sdk dependencies that not supported on this platform:

firebase_core|lib/firebase_core.dart
myapp|lib/pages/home.dart
myapp|lib/pages/upload.dart
platform|lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart
google_api_availability|lib/src/google_api_availability.dart
location_permissions|lib/src/location_permissions.dart
firebase_storage|lib/firebase_storage.dart
image_picker|lib/image_picker.dart
flutter_svg|lib/svg.dart
flutter_svg|lib/src/utilities/http.dart
flutter_svg|lib/src/picture_provider.dart
cached_network_image|lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart
flutter_cache_manager|lib/src/cache_store.dart
flutter_cache_manager|lib/src/web_helper.dart
flutter_cache_manager|lib/src/file_info.dart
flutter_cache_manager|lib/src/cache_manager.dart
sqflite|lib/src/factory_mixin.dart
sqflite|lib/src/factory_impl.dart
path_provider|lib/path_provider.dart

https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-resolve-skipped-compiling-warnings
```

I followed the link at the bottom and tried to apply what it said to my yaml file with no avail (I'm barely yaml literate). Any suggestions would be appreciated! Below is my yaml file.

```
name: myapp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7+2
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+2
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  geolocator: 5.0.1
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  image: ^2.0.7
  animator: 0.1.4
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image:
  flutter_svg:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
  assets:
    - assets/images/google_signin_button.png
    - assets/images/upload.svg
    - assets/images/search.svg
    - assets/images/activity_feed.svg
    - assets/images/no_content.svg
```

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the packages may not be web-aware. So for instance image_picker is in your list and I can't see how that could work properly in a browser.
You might be best commenting them all out and adding them one at a time.